# How to change the color of the status bar in chrome on android with a dark theme?

Tags: html, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, statusbar, manifest.json

I faced such a problem - despite the manifest and the meta tag, when I enable the dark theme for android, the status bar above my site does not turn into the desired color (black), but always remains gray. When using the light theme, the problem disappears. Can anyone come across a similar one and know how to fix it?

*meta tag*

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
```

*part of manifest.json*

```
{
    "theme_color": "#000000",
    "background_color": "#000000"
}
```

**Here are photos with a dark and light theme:**

[Dark theme, status bar for some reason gray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2yma.jpg)

[Light theme, status bar black, as it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNWTN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Ok solution to your problem is

1. Save color in session / browser cookie and change the HTML color value
2. Altering manifest.json file (on server) - but this is not a good idea as manifest.json is cached (and generally they update it [24 hours](https://web.dev/manifest-updates/#cr-desktop))